# Can not set up kafka server on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new in Kafka, and I follow the instruction on the official website.

when I ready to run the kafka server

[image]

> there is an error the log4j.properties was unexpected at this time.

Comment: I'm not sure what this specific issue is, but if you're considering windows for a production kafka server, i will strongly recommend you reconsider. It's a nightmare.

Comment: I think PowerShell shouldn't be used to run those bat files. Try CMD? Try Docker images?

Comment: when i have to I use GitBash under windows and the .sh version instead of the .bat

Comment: Run it on CMD, it works perfectly fine there

Comment: I have tried cmd and GitBash but they didn't work neither. The cmd give me the same error and GitBash require me to run gradle for compiling first, and I think this way may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I kept Kafka distribution inside C:\Program Files (x86). This directory is having whitespaces which causes this issue.
To resolve it I placed Kafka installation folder directly into C:\ drive as below

```
C:\kafka_2.12-2.2.0
```

Now I am able to run zookeeper as below

```
 C:\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties
```

Just try this, I believe it will work.